# Filter according to partial match of string variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a data-frame with string variable column "disease". I want to filter the rows with partial match "trauma" or "Trauma". I am currently done the following using `dplyr` and `stringr`:

```
trauma_set <- df %>% filter(str_detect(disease, "trauma|Trauma"))
```

But the result also includes "Nontraumatic" and "nontraumatic". How can I filter only "trauma, Trauma, traumatic or Traumatic" without including nontrauma or Nontrauma? Also, is there a way I can define the string to detect without having to specify both uppercase and lowercase version of the string (as in both trauma and Trauma)?

Comment: Use `\\b(trauma|Trauma)`

Comment: Also, may be `df %>% filter(str_detect(disease, regex("\\btrauma", ignore_case = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to specify the word boundary, use `\\b` at the start.  Also, for different cases, we can use `ignore_case = TRUE` by wrapping with `modifiers`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
out <- df %>%
        filter(str_detect(disease, regex("\\btrauma", ignore_case = TRUE)))

sum(str_detect(out$disease, regex("^Non", ignore_case = TRUE)))
#[1] 0
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(disease = sample(c("Nontraumatic", "Trauma", 
 "Traumatic", "nontraumatic", "traumatic", "trauma"), 50 ,
        replace = TRUE), value = rnorm (50))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I know what ^ is supposed to do in "^Non" ?

Comment: @dc.tv The `^` in regex implies the start of the string.  Here, I just wanted to show that after the `filter` step (based on my example) there are no rows with `Non` for the 'disease' column

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to a correct solution, you just needed to add the "start of string" anchor `^`, as follows:

```
trauma_set <- df %>% filter(str_detect(disease, "^trauma|^Trauma"))
```